# Force GridView To Create Not Recycle Controls

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a GridView in a windows store app that has an ItemContainerStyleSelector.  Within the style is an Image control that has a custom dependency property to set the source (This is so I can get a handle on the Image and hook up to the unloaded event).
My issue is the Image is never unloaded and seems to be reused.  This means that when I set the source, the image is set on other items in the GridView as well (For Example I have an object which has no image but after scrolling away and then back again it has an image from another object).

I've tried to set virtualization mode to standard where I can but it doesn't help. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Image that is contained in the style.  This is passed to a method "OnRemoteURISourceChanged" when set.  I'd expect a different image control whenever the method is called but this is not the case.

```
<Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" DataContext="{Binding CurrentBackdrop}" helpers:ImageExtensions.RemoteURISource="{Binding Uri}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

And here is my GridView

```
<GridView x:Name="ItemsGrid" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BrowseResults}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="20,0,20,0"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemsGrid_ItemClick" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <controls:UPnPCDStyleSelector CDObject="{StaticResource somestyle1}" Container="{StaticResource somestyle2}" Item="{StaticResource somestyle3}"/>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
```

UPDATE: The issue appears to be the WrapGrid.  If I change this to a VirtualizingStack Panel and set the VirtualizationMode to Standard then everything works as expected but obviously my items then only appear on one line and not multiple lines as I wish.

How do I set the virtualization mode of a WrapGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance your `helpers:ImageExtensions.RemoteURISource` doesn't clear the `Image.Source` when either your `CurrentBackdrop` property or its `Uri` property value is null?

Comment: It most certainly is Virtualized. It's the recycling over standard virtualization that's causing me issues. It inherits from VirtualizingPanel->OrientatedVirtualizingPanel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid

Comment: My bad. All the more interesting what your extension is doing there.

Comment: It basically takes the source and sets the image source in an Async method.  Because it's a DP I have access to the Image control so don't have to return a blank BitmapImage as I would in a converter. This means you don't see a blank image for a short time whilst changing images.  It also waits for the image control to be unloaded so the Async task can be cancelled if not required anymore. All this works great with a VirtualizingStackPanel with virtualization set to standard but with a WrapGrid the images are never unloaded until the page is left and the same image control is reused.

Comment: I have a feeling sharing an isolated repro project would be the best way for you to get more eyes on the problem.

Comment: There might just be too many forces at play to get you a straight answer without a test case unless someone had the same problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the task which is loading the img source returns to default ui context when awaiting? I don't think it is a good idea to set Image.Source property form code. The better solution would be to create a custom observable task class and bind im source to it's result. In the background you can call the task. Do you need the control to be Image? Because if it would be a control with template, it would be easier for you to do that. I can send you the class which does that if you want to.